# Process for developing DNN skins or modules without uploading after every single change

Tags: dotnetnuke, dotnetnuke-module, dotnetnuke-7

While our team is starting work on our first DNN 7 sites, we're running into a small impediment. It would seem that the development cycle for a skin or module is that for every single little change you make, you need to create a new package and upload it to DNN. Our engineers are worried that they'll get caught in a loop of:

1. Tweak CSS
2. Create zip for skin
3. Upload zip to DNN
4. Go to step 1 until skin is complete

Consider this to also be a metaphor for module development. Is there a better process to develop modules and skins? Should we create the initial skin package, tweak the installed version, and then update the original files?

Edit: It's our intention to keep the installable skin and module files under source control in TFS, and deploying packages as changes are made.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you're developing those skins locally, running at a URL like http://dnndev.me/ you can make all the changes you want, without having to package/install the skins.

That is also the recommended approach for doing module development.

Here's a tutorial on setting up your local development environment:

http://www.christoc.com/Tutorials/All-Tutorials/aid/1

If you aren't doing local development, than you have to go through the hoops for packaging/deploying or uploading to the webserver via FTP/file system.

Comment: Thanks Chris, I appreciate it. We'll be doing local development in our development environments, but I think I'm still missing something. For example, if I have a VS project with my skin in it, how to I let DNN know about it without creating a zip and installing the zip in DNN?

Comment: If it is in the /portals/_default/skins/skinname folder DNN will automatically see it.

Answer (score 1):

For modules, you can install the module only one time and then just recopy the dlls and the DesktopModules controls as a build. You can write batch files to automate the whole copy/paste process.